# Copy files from bucket to local dir

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I want to copy files from my bucket but only files/directories that not exist on local drive.

Is it possible?

I tried something like

```
gsutil -m rsync -n -r "MyBUCKET" "my_local_dir"
```

but something is wrong.

Comment: What is wrong? Can you detail your errors?

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the recently-added `-i` flag, which ignores existing files on the destination. That flag was added in [this commit](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/commit/1f43a62643b5d98e1c934c844bbd16ced78e05a4) and should be available as of gsutil v4.59.